# run two functions with loops in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a cubieboard and accessing the GPIO pins. one GPIO pin has an output to an LED which turns it on and off every 1000ms when running this function:

```
def testRunning():
    while 1:
        wiringpi2.digitalWrite(pin3,HIGH)
        wiringpi2.delay(1000)
        wiringpi2.digitalWrite(pin3,LOW)
        wiringpi2.delay(1000)
```

next I have a function to listen for a button press on another GPIO pin and when this is set to high (1) it causes another red LED to flash 20 times (I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it):

```
def stopButton():
    while 1:
        wiringpi2.pinMode(52,0) 
        stopBut = wiringpi2.digitalRead(52) 
        print (stopBut) # this is just for debugging
        wiringpi2.delay(500)
        if (stopBut == 1):
            break

    redBlink = int(0)
    while (redBlink < int(20)):
        wiringpi2.digitalWrite(pin2,HIGH) 
        wiringpi2.delay(50)
        wiringpi2.digitalWrite(pin2,LOW) 
        wiringpi2.delay(50)
        redBlink += int(1)
        print redBlink
```

Both of these work just as excepted when run separately.

Now I want to run both of these at the same time so the testRunning LED is blinking until the stopButton is pressed and the red LED blinks and the program stops. I've tried this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target = stopButton()).start()
    Process(target = testRunning()).start()
```

When running this code the stopButton is executed and sits waiting for the button press as expected but the testRunning code is not executed until the stoButton code has finished running (IE the button is pressed the LED is looped 20times and that function exits).

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can think of `()` as the call operator. `Process(target = stopButton()).start()` calls `stopButton()`, waits for it to complete, then passes its return value (`None`) to the `Process` constructor.

Use `Process(target = stopButton).start()` instead.

Comment: seems to work nicely without going down a threading route. How would I stop all processes from running at then end of this script? I.E when the stopButton() function has finished I want it to stop any other processes that could be simultaneously running

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some sort of parallel processing for this to work as well as create a way to interrupt your running thread.

Read up on [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and create and start your two `Thread` objects, one for each method. The overall approach I'd take is to read a boolean in your `testRunning()` method and to write to it in your `stopButton()` method.

```
if not keepRunning:
    return
```

and insert that just before each of your `wiringpi2.digitalWrite()` calls. You can be a little more advanced by using `notify()` with a timeout to cause the `stopButton()` to end the `testRunning()` method instantly instead of on the delay.

Last tricky part: remember to `join()` your threads after starting them.

```
import threading
import sys

checkRunState = threading.Condition()
keepRunning = True

def stopButton():
    # since I didn't set up objects, use a global
    global keepRunning
    # block until the enter key is pressed
    sys.stdin.readline()
    keepRunning = False
    # acquire because that must be done before making an action
    # then notify anything that needs to know if we're still supposed
    # to keep running
    checkRunState.acquire()
    checkRunState.notifyAll()
    checkRunState.release()
    print "HAMMER TIME"

def blinky():
    global keepRunning
    checkRunState.acquire()
    redBlink = int(0)
    while (redBlink < int(20)):
        redBlink += int(1)
        # instead of a sleep(), use this for timing since it will
        # be woken up right away if the stop condition changes
        checkRunState.wait(.1)
        if not keepRunning:
            checkRunState.release()
            return
        print "blinky!"
    checkRunState.release()

stopper = threading.Thread(target=stopButton)
stopper.daemon = True
blinker = threading.Thread(target=blinky)

blinker.start()
stopper.start()

blinker.join()
# stopper() never unblocks. Setting it as a daemon thread
# means that python won't keep running because of it and we
# shouldn't try to join it
```